# How to make python 3.9 my default python interpreter on centos

Tags: python, centos, vps

I recently installed python3 on my vps, I want to enable it as default, so that when I type
`python` I get python 3. I think the problem is its installed in `/usr/local/bin` instead of /usr/bin/ typing `python` on the terminal access python2 typing `python3` returns `bash: python3: command not found` 
Most answers I have seen is a bit confusing as I am not a centos expert.

Comment: Actually, you don't really want to set Python globally to anything other than chosen by the distribution, especially on an enterprise OS like CentOS. Your need for another Python version is understandable. For this, you can/should use Python virtual environments.

Comment: I have done this with ubuntu this has always been a breeze for me, I just install python and install pipenv create my environment and am done! but I couldn't with centos, after my first installation I was only able to access python3.9 by well typing python3.9 on the terminal. the app I want to host is running on python 3.9 I can't seem to find a way to configure pipenv to user python3.9

Answer (score 0):

for a  simple fix, you can use alias

add the alias to your .bashrc file

sudo vi ~/.bashrc

then add your alias at the bottom

alias python="python3.9"

So that when you type python you'll get python 3

Answer (score -1):

There're several ways.

First, check if `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your $PATH variable:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it is indeed not there, you may want to add this line to your `.bashrc` file (assuming you're using bash):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

This will add `/usr/local/bin` to your $PATH variable and will make `python3` accessible after you relaunch a terminal session.

Now, changing the default `python` globally might not be a good a idea as there could be system software depending on `python` command pointing to python2.

What you could do is use PyEnv which will allow you using different python versions on your computer: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: Indeed it's not in PATH, do I need to do this if I reboot the system?

Comment: After adding the command `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` I get this error `python3
bash: python3: command not found`

Comment: just to confirm - you are sure that `python3` in `/usr/local/bin`, you have added the command to the `~/.bashrc`, restarted terminal and it still does not work?

Comment: I have completely ruined my vps now, I tried reinstalling the .configure --prefix=/usr it installed the first time, good then I tried to install pip and ended up installing pip for python 3.6 and the version I installed was python3.9 safe to say it's a hot mess now.

Comment: it is almost impossible to debug things in this way. I would suggest either reinstalling OS from scratch instead of trying to fix it or trying to undo things if you were doing it through command line and your bash_history is accurate